# How to traverse to each condition in IF condition using ANTLR java grammar

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I'm building a language parsing tool for Java where I want to capture all the conditional expression for if and else-if.

So, I have written listen and override the enterStatement().

```
public void enterStatement(@NotNull apexParser.StatementContext ctx) {
    if( ctx.IF() != null ) {
        // System.out.println(ctx.IF().getSourceInterval());

        TokenStream tokens = parser.getTokenStream();
        System.out.println(tokens.getText(ctx.IF().getSourceInterval()));
        System.out.println(parser.getTokenStream().getText(ctx));

        //System.out.println(ctx.IF().getText());
        //System.out.println(ctx.toStringTree(parser));
        //System.out.println(ctx.IF().getSymbol().getText());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to traverse each condition used here.

Example:
if( a > 1 && b < 0)

Just want to know how I can traverse through the condition tree.

**NOTE**: I'm very new in ANTLR tool, please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: what grammar are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your follow up, I was using Java grammar file.

Finally, I was able to find the solution to traverse individual nodes using below code.

```
@Override
public void enterStatement(@NotNull apexParser.StatementContext ctx) {
    System.out.println(this.thisClass + "." + this.thisMethod);
    if( ctx.IF() != null ) {
        // System.out.println(ctx.IF().getSourceInterval());

        for(int i = 0; i < ctx.parExpression().getChild(1).getChildCount(); i++) {
            if( ctx.parExpression().getChild(1).getChild(i).getChildCount() > 1 ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < ctx.parExpression().getChild(1).getChild(i).getChildCount(); j++ ) {
                    System.out.println(ctx.parExpression().getChild(1).getChild(i).getChild(j).getText());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(ctx.parExpression().getChild(1).getChild(i).getText());
            }
        }

        //TokenStream tokens = parser.getTokenStream();
        //System.out.println(tokens.getText(ctx.IF().getSourceInterval()));
        //System.out.println(parser.getTokenStream().getText(ctx));

        //System.out.println(ctx.IF().getText());
        //System.out.println(ctx.toStringTree(parser));
        //System.out.println(ctx.IF().getSymbol().getText());
    }
}
```

Just posting it here so that it may help others.

NOTE: I know my code is not optimized, it's just a hint to go further.